# Unable to explode object

Tags: physics

I haven't been able to get the fragments of the green object to explode.  I'm not sure why, since I added physics, rigid bodies and made it active.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the .blend:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object that you want to explode is one solid object. In order for it to explode you must first break it up into pieces.

I took the following steps:

- *Edit mode* >*Remove doubles*
- *Object mode* run cell fracture
- Move object on layer one to a secondary/ unused layer and
  move fractures to layer one
- Add active rigid body physics to all fractures with *collision margin*
  enabled at 1

[image]

- Bake simulation then play the animation

[image]
[image]